# SQLite select query with like condition in reverse

Tags: php, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to write a query in php that will select a row from a database that partially matches a string.

Better explained via an example:

Say my DB has a field called `numberString`, with value 'abcd'.  I want to write a query that, given "123abcd", will return a field of that row of the database.

```
SELECT mood 
  FROM USERS 
 WHERE numberString like '%$giveNumberString'"
```

`$giveNumberString` is the functions parameter (i.e. the string that I want to look for)

But I think those two `numberString` and `'%$givenNumberString'"` should be like the other way around in order for the query to work as expected.  Is there a way to do this?

---

Ok the table looks like this:

```
id | username | numberString | mood
-------------------------------------
1  | myUsrNam | abcd         | happy
```

Now I want, given "123abcd", to retrieve the mood of that person. In other words to match 123abcd against abcd.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. could you post an example table contents, and what you want to retrieve?

Comment: @Mat Have a look I edited the question! Cheers!

Comment: It's debatable if [Full Text Search](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) will work for your requirement.  It's not wrong to expect users to learn to search better - garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @OMG Ponies Thats not really an option for me though! I like your nickname btw :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a legal syntax, but let me try a wild guess: have you tried

```
SELECT mood from users where '$giveNumberString' like '%' || numberString || '%'
```

?

Comment: SQLite uses `||` as concatenation operator.  Replace the `+`es by `||` and this should work.  Though I think you only need the first '%', and not the second.

Comment: @Martijn: yes, I though `+` was not valid... the edited answer looks fine.

Comment: @mixkat What does it do? Saying "this doesn't work" cannot help anyone help you!

Comment: @llya True sorry!It was returning random stuff! I found that the solution to this is SELECT mood from users2 where '$givenNumberString' like concat('%',number);  Cant really explain it but it works for me and it kinda makes sense in my head :)

Comment: @mixkat Great! So it's `concat` - mental note taken. Good luck :)