# SQL select query with wildcard on input parameter

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, wildcard, sql-like

Same question as my [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451285/sqlite-select-query-with-like-condition-in-reverse) basically!

I have a db table and I need to write a query that will return results based on a partial match of a string.

```
Example: 

DB field: abc 

Search term: 123abc

i.e. I want given 123abc for it to return the row that has the abc field in it!

My attempt:

SELECT mood from users where '$searchTerm' like '%' || dbField
```

Is something like that possible in any way?

---

Well basically I'm trying to match the numbers with the search term `la77740985`

```
id   | mood  | numberfield
====   =====   ============
1      bad      '77740985'
2      good     '77513755'
```

Running the query returns both rows!

Note: The wildcard should only be in the beginning of the string in other words I want the search term to begin with anything but still match the string from the database that basically have the same ending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked like this:

SELECT mood from users where '$searchTerm' like  concat('%',numberField);

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mood
from users
where '$searchTerm' like '%' || numberField
```

This will match $searchTerm = '123abc' against dbField that contains 'abc'.  It's correct.  If you need contains (anywhere), then add `|| '%'` at the end.

Full test script

```
drop table if exists users2;
create table users2 (mood, numberfield);
insert into users2(mood,numberfield) values ('happy','77740985');
insert into users2(mood,numberfield) values ('sad','77513755');
```

Then run this

```
SELECT mood from users2 where 'la77740985' like ('%' || numberfield);
```

Output

```
mood
=======
'happy'
```

Comment: @Richard Yeah but it also matches other irrelevant fields for some reason!

Comment: @mixkat - can you list out some examples (edit question) - see my edited answer as well

Comment: @Richard It doesnt on mine! It returns both fields!

Comment: @mixkat please edit question with `both fields` and the value of $searchTerm so we can work on the same page

Comment: @Richard I only need the wildcard in the beginning of the string! I'll re-edit the question!

Comment: @mixkat - I'm not sure what version of SQLite you are using. The query should be correct and checks out in SQLite Manager for Firefox

Comment: @Richard Now that returns nothing!

Comment: @Richard The SQL version is 5.0.81!

Comment: @Richard Sorry it took me so long! i didnt notice you edited the answer! I ran your queries but it doesnt work! it doesnt return anything!Does this work for you?