# Sqlite reverse glob: The glob string is stored in the table and the constant string is in the query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose I have this table:

```
name|match
a   |*
b   |?
c   |THIS
d   |THAT
```

Given a value via a replaceable parameter (`?`), I would like to select the rows where that value is matched by the glob pattern in `match`.

Examples:

1. Given `?` == `THIS` expect the query to return rows `a` and `c`.
2. Given `?` == `SELF` expect the query to return row `a`.
3. Given `?` == `A` expect the query to return rows `a`, and `b`.

This does not work:

```sql
SELECT name from table WHERE match GLOB ?
```

My feeling is the way to achieve the desired behaviour is query without `GLOB` and then manually perform the glob in the code calling the query.

Comment: Is that anything like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451285/sqlite-select-query-with-like-condition-in-reverse?rq=2? Just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the operands backwards.

```sql
SELECT `name` FROM `table` WHERE ? GLOB `match`
```

Comment: My question: How to reverse glob?... Your answer: Reverse the operands... Amazingly simple!